# How to query the inverse side of a many to many relationship with Doctrine

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, many-to-many

I want to know which professional diseases are included in all the medical records of a company production unit. The entity MedicalRecord has a many to many relationship with DiseaseTypology as follows:

```
/**
 * AppBundle\Entity\HealthData\MedicalRecord
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="medical_record")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="MedicalRecordRepository")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class MedicalRecord
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var string $companyProductionUnitId
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="company_production_unit_id", type="integer",nullable=true)
     */
    protected $companyProductionUnitId;

    /**
     * @var ArrayCollection $professionalDiseases
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\HealthData\Core\DiseaseTypology")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="medical_record_professional_disease",
     *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="medical_record_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="professional_disease_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
     *      )
     *
     */
    protected $professionalDiseases;
```

In the MedicalRecordReposity class I created the following method:

```
public function getProfessionalDiseasesByProductionUnit($productionUnitId)
{
    $em = $this->getEntityManager();

    $repository = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:MedicalRecord');

    return $repository->createQueryBuilder('m')
        ->select('m.professionalDiseases')
        ->where('m.companyProductionUnitId = :productionUnitId')
        ->setParameter('productionUnitId', $productionUnitId)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getArrayResult();
}
```

But I get the error:

> [Semantical Error] line 0, col 9 near 'professionalDiseases': Error: Invalid PathExpression. Must be a StateFieldPathExpression.

How to query the inverse side of a many to many relationship? Thank you!

Comment: May be these [answer 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22666692/invalid-pathexpression-must-be-a-statefieldpathexpression-in-query-builder-wi) and [answer 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34408073/error-invalid-pathexpression-must-be-a-statefieldpathexpression) can help you to improve your question, or answer it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if I can understand what you want, but here's my try:

```
class MedicalRecordRepository extends \Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository
{
    public function getProfessionalDiseasesByProductionUnit($productionUnitId)
    {
        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('m');

        $qb
            ->select('m, pd')
            ->innerJoin('m.professionalDiseases', 'pd')
            ->where('m.companyProductionUnitId = :productionUnitId')
            ->setParameter('productionUnitId', $productionUnitId)
        ;

        return $qb->getQuery()->getArrayResult();
    }
}
```

Explanation: i think you need a join between `MedicalRecord` and `DiseaseTypology`, and for that, if you have this setup (in both your entities):

```
#Entity/MedicalRecord.php
private $companyProductionIUnitId;

/**
 * @var \AppBundle\Entity\DiseaseTypology
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\DiseaseTypology", mappedBy="medicalRecords")
 */
private $professionalDiseases;
```

First, you have to have that `mappedBy` option, to tell doctrine the inverse side of the relationship.

And

```
# Entity/DiseaseTypology.php
/**
 * @var \AppBundle\Entity\MedicalRecord
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\MedicalRecord", inversedBy="professionalDiseases")
 */
private $medicalRecords;
```

You have to have that `inversedBy` option to tell doctrine the owning side of the relationship.

Once we've clarified that, to let doctrine do its things related to joins, you just need to tell it on which field to make the join. And as in my example, the relation between `MedicalRecord` and `DiseaseTypology` is made through `$professionalDiseases` fields. So this one will be the field to make the join with:

```
->innerJoin('m.professionalDiseases', 'pd') // this professionalDiseases is the $professionalDiseses from MedicalRecord entity
```

Ok, I've did all those explanations, because I saw how you've did your query, and I feel is not the right approach.

And my results after running the `getProfessionalDiseasesByProductionUnit()` method was like this:

[image]

Comment: Your suggestion is ok, but the query returns an array of medical records with the related professional diseases. I would have liked to receive an array of professional diseases directly for all the medical records with a particular company unit. Is it possible? Thx

Comment: @Gianluca78 If I understood you well, you need an array of professional diseses for each medical record, based on a particular company unit ?

Comment: I need an array of all the professional diseases identified in the medical records having a certain company id. Example: $professionalDiseasesForCompanyUnit = array('disease 1', 'disease 2', 'disease 44')

Comment: Ok I realized what to do! I made an error with the model. Sorry for bothering you again...

Answer (score 1):

*Note: Use getResult() instead of getArrayResult(), because you fetch entities (DiseaseTypology), not set of fields*

There are 2 options here:

1. **Make relation MedicalRecord <=> DiseaseTypology bidirectional** [See documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-many-bidirectional). Then your method would look very simple:

   ```
   public function getProfessionalDiseasesByProductionUnit($productionUnitId)
   {
       $em = $this->getEntityManager();

       $repository = $em->getRepository(DiseaseTypology::class);

       return $repository->createQueryBuilder('dt')
           ->select('dt')
           ->join('dt.medicalRecords', 'm')
           ->where('m.companyProductionUnitId = :productionUnitId')
           ->setParameter('productionUnitId', $productionUnitId)
           ->getQuery()
           ->getResult();
   }
   ```
2. **Keep existing DB structure and add some logic after query**

   ```
   public function getProfessionalDiseasesByProductionUnit($productionUnitId)
   {
       $em = $this->getEntityManager();

       $repository = $em->getRepository(MedicalRecord::class);

       $mediaRecords = $repository->createQueryBuilder('m')
           ->select('m, dt')
           //note: with this join all professionalDiseases will be loaded within one query for all MedicalRecords
           ->join('m.professionalDiseases', 'dt')
           ->where('m.companyProductionUnitId = :productionUnitId')
           ->setParameter('productionUnitId', $productionUnitId)
           ->getQuery()
           ->getResult();

       $professionalDiseases = [];
       foreach($mediaRecords as $mediaRecord) {
           foreach($mediaRecord->professionalDiseases as $professionalDisease) {
               $professionalDiseases[professionalDisease->id] = $professionalDisease;
           }
       }

       return $professionalDiseases;
   }
   ```